# Input to JavaFX from JSP

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-ee-6

I want to give dynamic input to Java FX application from a JSP page. I am not able to find any suitable way.
Dynamic in the sense that I want to give input to JavaFX application based on user input in a JSP page. I am embedding the same Java FX application in the same JSP page.
Any help is welcome regarding the same.
I want to give input to Java FX application when it is running through JSP page.

Answer (score 1):

See the JavaFX deployment topic: [Accessing a JavaFX Application from a Web Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_javascript.htm#BCEIBFGD).

The JavaScript => JavaFX interface in JavaFX is the same as that used for a traditional Java applet - it makes use of a technology known as LiveConnect.  Further documentation on using LiveConnect is in the LiveConnect documentation topic: [Calling from JavaScript to Java](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#INTRODUCTION).

The JavaFX documentation provides the following sample code:

*Java Code*

```
package testapp;

public class MapApp extends Application {
    public static int ZOOM_STREET = 10;

    public static class City {
        public City(String name) {...}
        ...
    }

    public int currentZipCode;

    public void navigateTo(City location, int zoomLevel) {...}
    ....
}
```

*JavaScript Code*

```
function navigateTo(cityName) {
    //Assumes that the Ant task uses "myMapApp" as id for this application
    var mapApp = document.getElementById("myMapApp");
    if (mapApp != null) {
        //City is nested class. Therefore classname uses $ char 
        var city = new mapApp.Packages.testapp.MapApp$City(cityName);
        mapApp.navigateTo(city, mapApp.Packages.testapp.MapApp.ZOOM_STREET);
        return mapApp.currentZipCode;
    }
    return "unknown";
}
window.alert("Area zip: " + navigateTo("San Francisco"));
```

Note the important comment in the JavaScript code "Assumes that the Ant task uses "myMapApp" as id for this application". The id referred to is the `placeholderid` parameter of the [fx:deploy task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm#CIABIFCI).

Now, because you are using a JSP, presumably the html page containing the application is dynamically generated by the JSP processor. So, what you may want to do is make use of the [fx:template](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CIACACDA) task to generate modified jsp source which invokes the [dtjava deployment script](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#BABJHEJA) to embed your target JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try: [HostServices.getWebContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#getWebContext%28%29)

Comment: but that way if anything changes from JSP page. How will JavaFX application will know about it.